# Configuring SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to configure a existing SharePoint environment to the standards set, so  my question is

Is it possible to change the path of virtual directory of the application after it has been deployed ? Will it cause any problems if i change the path of virtual directory in IIS now ??

Can i also delete the sharepoint-80 site ??

The environment has  the app\web in one server and db in other.

Comment: What you mean by changing Path of virtual directory? You mean the physical path?

Comment: I'm similarly confused. If you're trying to change the virtual path in IIS, I'd avoid doing that. Once it's set up, leave it. If you're looking to change the web application's path, e.g. from portal.example.com to foo.example.com, please see this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/02/27/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx. If you're looking to change the path to a SC's root web, to my knowledge you'll have to backup the subweb, delete it, then restore it to a new path.

Comment: I want to change the physical path of the existing web application in the IIS . The physical path currently points "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virturaldirectories" ...I want to know the impact of changing the existing physical path to a differen location .